How to calculate the upper bound of the difference between Renyi entropies of different orders?
The definition of Renyi entropy is:
$$H_\alpha(X)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}log\sum_{i}p_i^\alpha$$.
My question is, given different $\alpha$, for example, $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_2=2$, what is the upper bound of the difference between the two entropies over all $D$-dimensional possible probability distributions:
$$H_{\alpha_1}(X)-H_{\alpha_2}(X)$$
I have thought about this problem for a while but go nowhere.
